# Does Backbone have a finally-Callback?

Tags: jquery-mobile, web-applications, backbone.js, try-catch-finally

I am currently creating a Backbone.js and jquery Mobile web application and I have some calls to Backbone.model.fetch().
I have the proper success and error-callbacks, but there is some code that I want to execute no matter if the fetch was successfull or not.

Currently, I'm simply copying the common code. But I asked myself if there is any callback that is executed no matter what happens.

Like the try{} catch{} finally{} from C#.
Is there anything like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

fetch() returns a 'Deferred Object'
see: http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

it's not really like  try{} catch{}, but you can use  .always()  method to bind a callback which will be executed after the request is done (no matter if it was successful or not)

like so.

```
 var doSomething = function () {
     //will run after fetch() request is finished
 };

 collection.fetch().always(doSomething);
```

similarly, instead of passing `success` or `error` callbacks to fetch()'s options, in general it is encouraged to chain .done(), .fail(), or .then() methods to deferred methods(fetch, save...etc)

Comment: Then I'm going to do it that way. Thanks.

Comment: I found out that using the done() event instead of the success-callback doesn't pass the id of the object to the argument of the function (the Backbone-Id). But I need that id in my function.

Comment: backbone passes the same arguments to the callbacks no matter if they are defined in the options hash or thru promises. Could you post your code to provide more details?

Comment: I had a

`this.user.fetch({
    success: function(user) {
        console.log(user.id);
    }
}).done(function(user) {
    console.log(user.id)
});`

First one shows "hakvdis988" (i made this value up). Second one shows "undefined". I think this is because the success-Callback passes the Backbone.Model (or something related) while the done()-Callback passes a normal javascript-object.

Comment: I see. You probably should not use the params passed to your callback in this case. since you are fetching `this.user`, once it's done, backbone is gonna assign the correct attributes on this.user, you should be able to use `console.log(this.user.id)` in your callbacks as long as the context `this` is set correctly.